# Populate Textbox with Nullable Session Variable On Page Load

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

not too sure where to start with this one, I'm very new to mvc.

in normal asp.net it would be a simple case of

```
if (sessionXYZ != null)
{ textbox.text = sessionXYZ.tostring()}
```

cant seem to get my head around this in MVC though.. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In normal ASP.NET you would not [access session variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx) in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MVC you would set up your model for the view and leave it's value as the nullable value, then assign it to your model and output it with

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.ValueFromSession);
```